# 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Linq.dll (Sequence contains no elements)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, exception, uwp

Getting the following exception in the code below and cannot figure out how to solve for it:

> ```
> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Linq.dll 
>
> Sequence contains no elements
> ```

The code is:

```
        return MenuSwitchInfo?
                .Where(ms => ms.IsActive)
                .Select(ms => ms.Id.ToString())
                .Aggregate( (a, b) => $"{a}, {b}" )
                .Trim();
```

I've also tried the following with no luck:

```
        return MenuSwitchInfo?
                .DefaultIfEmpty()
                .Where(ms => ms.IsActive)
                .Select(ms => ms.Id.ToString())
                .Aggregate( (a, b) => $"{a}, {b}" )
                .Trim()
```

MenuSwitchInfo is an ObservableCollection.
Any ideas on how to solve for this?

Comment: You can't figure it out because you believe some falsehood. The problem is best solved by first determining what false belief you have, then stop believing that and start believing something true. *What do you believe `Aggregate` does when given an empty sequence? Do you believe that the result of the `Where` is a non-empty sequence?*  Find the false belief and the problem will be easier to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check exceptions section of the docs for the [`Aggregate<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource,TSource,TSource>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=net-8.0#system-linq-enumerable-aggregate-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-0-0)))):

> **InvalidOperationException**
> `source` contains no elements.

i.e. for empty collection this overload will result in corresponding exception.

You can provide the seed (i.e. initial accumulator value) so `Aggregate` will not throw for empty collections (see the docs for [corresponding overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=net-8.0#system-linq-enumerable-aggregate-2(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-1-system-func((-1-0-1))))) and handle it for the first iteration. Something along these lines (not tested):

```
return MenuSwitchInfo?
    .Where(ms => ms.IsActive)
    .Select(ms => ms.Id.ToString()) // also you can remove this select and handle the transform in the Aggregate 
    .Aggregate((string)null, (a, b) => a is null ? b : $"{a}, {b}");
    ?.Trim();
```

But I would recommend to use `string.Join` which should be more perfromance effective AFAIK:

```
return string.Join(", ", MenuSwitchInfo?.Where(ms => ms.IsActive)
        .Select(ms => ms.Id.ToString())
    ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>());
```

Though this will return empty string for both null and empty collections.

Comment: wow!! That's something new I learned from your answer +1.

Answer (score -1):

It's probably the Aggregate method throwing that exception.
Try this:

```
return MenuSwitchInfo == null || !MenuSwitchInfo.Any() ? null :
                MenuSwitchInfo
                .Where(ms => ms.IsActive)
                .Select(ms => ms.MenuSwitchId.ToString())
                .Aggregate( (a, b) => $"{a}, {b}" )
                .Trim()
```